# How do I convert imperfect datetime string to datetime object

Tags: javascript

I have an example datetime string "Today, Fri May 12 2023 at 07:00:00, we go swimming". I use the new Date(string) and it gives invalid date.

Is there regex script to convert that string to valid date?

Comment: It looks like this kind of task is best solved by applying some kind of artificial intelligence (chatGPT and the like ...).

Comment: You have only this format or strings with many other formats? If this is the only format, we can use some hacks to parse it. But if there are many different formats, then first try to unify it.

Comment: If you only have date and time in the string, something like Sugar.js has some pretty advanced parsing. It can interpret "Today at 07:00:00" or "May 12 at 7 AM", for example. But parsing free-form text that could include just about anything is really difficult, and sometimes it's ambiguous enough to be impossible to do correctly. In the example you've given, what would you expect to happen if "Today" was not "May 12"? Should it choose May 12, or today's date? There's no answer that's guaranteed to match the intent of the person entering the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(Today,)? ([A-Z]{3}) ([a-z]{3}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{4}) at ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}), (.*)$
```

Once the regex has matched the string, use the following code to convert it to a valid date:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
matchedString,
"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

The string will be parsed into a DateTime object using the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method in this code. The 'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture' argument specifies that the date should be parsed using the invariant culture, which is the culture that is independent of the user's location.

Comment: Which language does this answer use? It's not JavaScript which is what the question is tagged with.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course convert a string if you know it follows that exact form. But I suppose that's not the case and you're looking for the ability to parse various sentences in free-form english that contain date and time information.

Parsing free-form language can't be done by a classic algorithm, with or without a regex. Humans can do so, and an AI can be trained to do so as well. You can send the sentence to ChatGPT's API for example, with a prompt asking it to return the date in standardized form. Even then, there might be sentences which are worded in a confusing way and would be interpretted wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest sanitizing your input(s), then using a dedicated datetime module such as [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) to parse the result.

We'd split and filter the string using a custom `sanitizeInput` function then use [DateTime.fromFormat](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat) to parse it.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;
const months = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'];

function dateComponentFilter(x) {
    x = x.toLowerCase();
    if (/\d{2,4}/.test(x)) { 
        return true;
    }
    if (/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/.test(x)) { 
        return true;
    }
    if (months.find(month => month === x)) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function sanitizeInput(input) {
    return input.split(/[,\s]/).filter(dateComponentFilter).join(' ')
}


const input = 'Today, Fri May 12 2023 at 07:00:00, we go swimming';
console.log('Input:          ', input);

const sanitizedInput = sanitizeInput(input);
console.log('Sanitized input:', sanitizedInput);

const d = DateTime.fromFormat(sanitizedInput, 'MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss');
console.log('Parsed date:    ', d.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.3.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```